# does firebase support query on array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database structured as below:

[image]

Trying to query data from the jobs array but always get a null back. Google arround but didn't get a clear answer whether firebase support query on array. Following is the code I used. Is there a way to get the array[1] back instead of null?

```
firebaseApp.database()
  .ref('tests')
  .orderByChild('jobs')
  .equalTo('bbb')
  .on("value",function(data){
      data.forEach(function(subdata){
        console.log('===> main.js', subdata.val());
      });
 }, function (errorObject) {
     console.log("===> main.js The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select the `jobs` node with `ref("tests/item1/jobs")` then since you are searching by value you have to order the items with [`orderByValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByValue).

[`equalTo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#equalTo) method behaves differently based on the applied ordering.

> The value to match for. The argument type depends on which orderBy*()
>   function was used in this query. Specify a value that matches the
>   orderBy*() type. When used in combination with orderByKey(), the value
>   must be a string.

```
firebaseApp.database()
  .ref("tests/item1/jobs")
  .orderByValue()
  .equalTo('bbb')
  .on("value",function(data){
      data.forEach(function(subdata){
        console.log('===> main.js', subdata.val());
      });
 }, function (errorObject) {
     console.log("===> main.js The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
 });
```

Comment: pls ignore my last comment. I double checked it and find a syntax error in my code. I am able to get the array back with your suggested code.

Comment: actually I have another issue, the "item1" in reference path is dynamic. So it is not known in advance. In this case what can we do? I tried ".child('jobs')" but it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for your help. Is is good to understand firebase database limits.

Comment: @sglai The current database api is quite limited. You have to get `tests` items and do the rest of filtering/selection on the client. `... .ref("tests").on("value" ...`. You're welcome.